# How to change a variable depending on what tile map a character is on

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want the statement "shade is" to be "shade is true" when the yellow square is on the red tile map. The statement should be "shade is" when the yellow square is on the orange tile map. I have given the yellow square a movement script so it can move around. [image: The picture shows the layout of the tile maps if that helps.]

Comment: Looks like you could just do this using coordinates if your boxes don't change size

Comment: How do I use coordinates.